# The role of どうも in 「犬は好きですが、猫はどうも･･･」

Tags: translation

In an [IMABI](https://www.imabi.net/theparticlewai.htm) tutorial on the は-particle, the following sentence is presented:

> 犬は好きですが、猫はどうも･･･

which translates to

> I like dogs, but cats...

What's throwing me off here is どうも. According to the dictionary, its meaning can be any of the following:

> [image]

In this case I assume it's functioning as a trailing Adverb (not an interjection). Is this the case? If so, none of those provided meanings seem to translate to "but...", as far as I can I tell.

Does anyone have any insight on what どうも is doing here (as far as literal translations go)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good way to think about どうも is "in every way (this way and that way)". The どう is "how" and when you add も we essentially get "every how way".

> 犬は好きですが、猫はどうも
>
> I like dogs, but as for cats, in every way (this way, that way, any
> way)... [I can't seem to like them.]

This definition is great when どうも is used to mean "Thank you" as well. For example if someone held the door open for you, you literally are saying: "In every way... [thank you]"

Answer (score 9):

How about thinking of it as "no matter how hard one may try (to, not to)" in definition #5?

> 犬は好きですが、猫はどうも・・・
> *Lit.* I like dogs but, speaking of cats, no matter how hard I try (to like them)...

Answer (score 4):

The #5 in jisho looks like missing in [the definition](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%82%82/#jn-156970) of 大辞泉, but I suppose the intention is what Chocolate's answer described.

That said, it is more proper (in terms of 大辞泉) to understand it as *somehow*.  大辞泉's def #2 has the following:

> 物事の原因や理由がはっきりわからない気持ちを表す。「―調子がおかしい」「**理数系は―苦手だ**」

The bolded example is exactly the same as 猫はどうも..., where 苦手だ is omitted. That is, *but* comes from the contrast between the preceding 犬は好きです and the omitted part.